# How to compile ActiveMQ Artemis with Maven

Tags: java, maven, activemq-artemis

Decided to build ActiveMQ Artemis from source. I downloaded Maven, downloaded the sources of the latest version of ActiveMQ Artemis, and run `mvn clean install`.
Running test:

```
Running org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.MainTest
[main] 11:24:17,381 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=/app/data,bindingsDirectory=/app/data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=/app/data/largemessages,pagingDirectory=/app/data/paging)
[main] 11:24:17,383 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
[main] 11:24:17,384 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
[main] 11:24:17,408 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock
[main] 11:24:17,408 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
[main] 11:24:17,801 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221007: Server is now live
[main] 11:24:17,802 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.29.0 [localhost, nodeID=1b803010-119c-11ee-a6dd-005056850eda]
```

It hangs indefinitely.
This is my first time doing this, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I don't want to skip tests. I just need help to determine why the test is not ending.

Comment: I realize you already marked an answer as correct, but it doesn't appear to actually answer your question about _why_ the test is failing and how to avoid skipping it. I believe my answer does that. Have you been able to review it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the build is hanging in the execution of a test. You could obviously dig into the details of the test to find out why it is hanging or you could also simply skip the execution of all tests like so:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

You should keep in mind though that this will skip all tests and tests usually exist for a reason. So, if you decide to contribute to ActiveMQ Artemis yourself, you should make sure to get the tests actually working first.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't want to skip tests.
I just need help to determine why the test is not ending.

Comment: In that case, you should probably open the test in your IDE of choice (IntelliJ or Eclipse) and search for the test class you mentioned in the first line of your test log and then search for the place where the last log message is emitted. You can then either read the source code or place a breakpoint and step through the test to see where it is hanging exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran `mvn clean install` from the `2.29.0` tag (i.e. the latest release) and everything worked fine.

I believe the issue you're seeing is environmental as the only test in [`org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.MainTest`](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.29.0/artemis-server/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/server/embedded/MainTest.java) *expects* that starting the broker will fail with a `java.io.IOException`, e.g.:

```
08:34:49,597 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222141: Node Manager can not open file /app/data/server.lock
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1035) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileBasedNodeManager.setUpServerLockFile(FileBasedNodeManager.java:145) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.setUpServerLockFile(FileLockNodeManager.java:111) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.start(FileLockNodeManager.java:102) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:694) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:608) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.EmbeddedActiveMQ.start(EmbeddedActiveMQ.java:134) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.Main.main(Main.java:76) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.MainTest.testNull(MainTest.java:28) [test-classes/:?]
    at ...
```

My hunch is that you actually have `/app/data/server.lock` which allows the broker to start successfully at which point it simply hangs. You should be able to work around this problem either by removing `/app/data/server.lock` or restricting read permissions to it.

I opened [ARTEMIS-4328](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4328) to deal with this problem.